# Package a Wordpress Plugin that is being Source Controlled using Git

Tags: php, eclipse, git, version-control, wordpress

I am using php to build a plugin for wordpress in eclipse and using git for source control. Eclipse's workspace is in my google drive.

I have completed writing all the code for the plugin now i want to put that code in my wordpress installation and this is what i am unable to figure out. I have seen the files in my google drive, they obviously do not have all the work i have done.

I understand the concept of stage, commit and branch. I have done some reading on "http://git-scm.com/".

Maybe i am misunderstanding a concept or just not search for the right keywords.

Can you please explain how to move the actual code to the wp installation?

Comment: I assume you want to create a zip file from your repository, git supports that: `git archive --format zip --output /full/path/to/zipfile.zip master`, see [exporting your repository - git ready](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/01/29/exporting-your-repository.html) - you can then upload that zipfile in your wordpress admin interface to install it as a new plugin.

Comment: Yep that is what i want, if you can make your comment as an answer i'll mark that as my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to create a zip file from your repository, git supports that:

```
$ git archive --format zip --output /full/path/to/zipfile.zip master
```

See [*exporting your repository - git ready*](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/01/29/exporting-your-repository.html) - you can then upload that zipfile in your wordpress admin interface to install it as a new plugin.